# dmd and gdc compiling code differently?

Tags: d, sdl-2, dmd, gdc, derelict3

I am currently trying out [DerelictSDL2](https://github.com/DerelictOrg/DerelictSDL2) (a binding to the SDL2 library for D) and I've written a code that successfully loads a JPG image and displays it in a window. That is, when it's compiled with dmd. When I try with gdc (and no code modification), it does compile but it won't load the image at runtime.

I believe I did things right :

`SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)`

then

`IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_JPG)`

and somewhere after that

`this.data = IMG_LoadTexture(Window.renderer, name.ptr)`

where `Window.renderer` is (obviously) the `SDL_Renderer*` and `name.ptr` is a `char*` pointing to the name of the image to load. But when compiling with gdc, `IMG_Load` and `IMG_LoadTexture` both return `null`, while with dmd they return a pointer to the newly created texture...

Did I forget something else (after all, with dmd it worked even without `IMG_Init`) ? Does Derelict only works with dmd (even if it's only interfacing to C functions) ?

dmd : 2.065

gdc : 4.9.1

**EDIT :**

Turns out the problem is completely different. `IMG_LoadTexture` takes a pointer to data for its second argument but `name.ptr` seems to only work with dmd. However If I try with a hard-coded argument like this :

`IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "../test/res/image.jpg")`

it works with both dmd and gdc.

Comment: It would help if you provided a complete minimal example, so that the readers can check what they get locally.

Comment: Now that you ask that, I have a code that works with both compilers... But I don't see what I did wrong with the long one; I even built the short one by copying pieces of the long one !

Comment: Yes, SSCCE please! ( http://sscce.org/ )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is no guarantee that D string will be 0-terminated. it just happens by chance with dmd. the correct way is to use toStringz() function from std.string module.

p.s. please note that string literals **are** 0-terminated, that's why hardcoded arguments works.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I don't think I would have found that by myself. Again, thanks !